# PostgreSQL on remote database: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached)?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I'm trying to put a huge data into PostgreSQL (PostGIS for detail).
About 100 scenes, each scene contains 12 bands of raster image. Each image is about 100MB
What I do:

```
For each scene in scenes (  
    for each band in scene (  
        Open connection to postGIS db  
        Add band  
    )  
    SET PGPASSWORD=password
    psql -h 192.168.2.1 -p 5432 -U user -d spatial_db -f combine_bands.sql
)
```

It ran well till scene #46. It causes an error **No buffer space available (maximum connections reached)**
I run script on Windows 7, my remote server is on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

**UPDATE:** Connect to remote server and run sql file.

Comment: Since it says "maximum connections reached" I'm going to guess you keep opening new connections and never closing the old ones. You don't say what your maximum number of connections is configured as but in any case many parallel inserts are unlikely to be the most efficient use of your disk I/O.

Comment: My script file, which contains connection string to remote db, do all the steps above. At Open-connection step, connection string is executed. I'm not sure psql can close connection automatically or not.

Comment: psql will close the connection when it finishes executing.

Comment: I'm confused now. If psql automatically close the connection when it finishes, then what causes "maximum connections reached".

Comment: Who knows? You haven't shown any actual code. You clearly *are* reaching the maximum connections though or you wouldn't get the message. Time to look at the config file and postgresql logs on your ubuntu server.

Comment: @RichardHuxton I have update my question. By the way, could you tell me where to find the config file in ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This message:

> No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?)

comes from a Java exception,  not the PostgreSQL server. A java stack trace may be useful to get some context.

If the connection was rejected by PostgreSQL, the message would be:

```
FATAL: connection limit exceeded for non-superusers
```

Still it may be that the program exceeds its max number of open sockets by not closing its connections to PostgreSQL. Your script should close each DB connection as soon as it's finished with it, or open just one and reuse it throughout the whole process.

Simultaneaous connections for the same program are only needed when issuing queries in parallel, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: Thank Daniel. I have updated the question. The message also says: Are you sure your remote is on port 5432. Besides, as I know the connection is automatically close. Or could you show me how to close psql in batch script?

Comment: @Jackie: I believe that message is not related to `psql`, but to the other stuff in your script.

Comment: Could you show me how to close psql connection in batch script or reuse a connection in batch script